# Refresh listView on return using onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, onactivityresult

**Explaining the structure:** In MainActivity I have a drawer menu and a fragment to display contents. From the drawer I can choose a category and a list of items in that category is read from database and is displayed in a listView in the content fragment.

When an item from the list view is clicked, a DetailActivity will start.

**Problem:** In the DetailActivity there is a button to remove the item from database. When this Item is pressed the DetailActivity closes. And the previous content fragment in the MainActivity is displayed. *(like pressing back button)* But  the problem is that the item I deleted is still shown in the listView. I have go to the relevant category so that the listView refreshes and that item isn't there anymore.

**What I expect:** What I want is that when I delete the item in the DetailActivity and return to the previous activity, the listView is automatically updated.

**What I've done:** I know I can use onActivityResult like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // Refresh Bookmarks page when a bookmark is deleted
    if (requestCode == LESSON_DETAIL_ACTIVITY && resultCode == -1) {
        datasource.open();
        lessons = datasource.findMyLessons();
        refreshDisplay(context, view, category, i); // Problem Here!
    }
}
```

As you see my refreshDisplay method takes 4 arguments. Originally these arguments are sent to the DetailActivity. *(when a list item is clicked in the fragment inside MainActivity)*
When I press "delete item" button in the DetailActivity and it closes. I don't know how to retrieve those argument so that I can refresh the list.

Here I post the code of my refreshDisplay method and how I call it just in case its needed.
I call refreshDisplay method inside a fragment (in the MainActivity) and the refreshDisplay itself is in the MainActivity.

```
public static class contentFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_CATEGORY_NUMBER = "category_number";
    public contentFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_content, container, false);
            int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_CATEGORY_NUMBER);
            String category = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.category)[i];

            ((MainActivity) this.getActivity()).refreshDisplay(this.getActivity(),rootView, category, i);

            getActivity().setTitle(category);
            return rootView;
        }
}
```

my refreshDisplay method is:

```
public void refreshDisplay(Context context, View view, String category, int i) {

    List<Lesson> lessonByCategory = datasource.findByCategory(category, i);

    final ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    final ArrayAdapter<Lesson> adapter = new LessonListAdapter(context, lessonByCategory);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);


    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.i(LOGTAG, "onListItemClick called");

            ArrayAdapter<Lesson> m_adapter = adapter;
            // get the Lesson object for the clicked row
            Lesson lesson = m_adapter.getItem(position);

            // use this if your `refreshDisplay()` method is in your activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LessonDetailActivity.class);

            isStared = datasource.isStared(lesson);

            intent.putExtra(".model.Lesson", lesson);
            intent.putExtra("isStared", isStared);

            startActivityForResult(intent, LESSON_DETAIL_ACTIVITY);

        }
    });
    }
```

Can anyone please help me?

**Edit 1:** In my code, in the *onActivityResult* I have called *refreshDisplay(context, view, category, i);* But please notice those arguments I have passed are not defined. Without the correct arguments refreshDisplay doesn't work!

**Edit 2:** I have a drawer navigation that contains a list of categories. When I click on one of the categories, In my content fragment the **onCreateView** calls **refreshDisplay** ** and puts **context** & **View** arguments plus **category** & **i** which are the name and position of the category chosen. Now **refreshDisplay** takes those arguments and and creates the list of items of that category and shows it in the content Fragment. refreshDisplay has a list adapter and listener that when clicked opens *DetailActivity*. From *DetailActivity* I can delete that item and *DetailActivity* is closed. I'm back to the list. The list still shows that deleted item. I want to update the list.

Comment: Why are you creating new list and setting adapter to that every time? Did you try by calling notifyDataSetChanged() method to the list view?

Comment: kameshwari is right but your code should work if the item deleted in listByCategory. So in your refreshDisplay(..) method you should delete the item that you have just now deleted in your detailactivity.do you get my point?

Comment: @Kameswari (1) I have one listView. So every time a different category is clicked, the listView is filled with relevant items. (2) I'm not familiar with notifyDataSetChanged(). How would it help?

Comment: can't you just return the deleted item id or something ..so that you can delete it from the list?

Comment: @KailashDabhi I don't know what arguments to give to the refreshDisplay method. If I knew how to retrieve the arguments then my problem is solve. But I don't know how to get them!

Comment: @niteshgoel Could you elaborate please

Comment: Look bro you dont need to give any argument just make the list listByCategory static and in detailActivity delete that entry and just refresh it.I dont why you are confuse.. try it..!

Comment: @KailashDabhi Could you please tell me how to refresh it?

Comment: @KailashDabhi I don't understand it

Comment: put your findLesson method also

Answer (score 0):

Just try my hints on you code .... I hope it might be solve your problem

1. call this method after delete item from you adapter. It will refresh the adapter content.

   notifyDataSetChanged()
2. You can pass the Context to following method as first param..

   refreshDisplay(/**this.getActivity()*/ context,rootView, category, i);

Comment: 1. I'm new to android. My adapter is in *refreshDisplay* and its final. So how can I use adaptor in *onActivityResult*     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: 2. There is no 'getActivity()' method available for 'this' in situation above.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:-

**declare your list listCategory static in your Activity class(global variable)**

**declare your listView as instance variable of your activity class.**

**In DetailActivity delete the listCategory item(You can access it cause it is static)**

    like this:-

```
      MainActivity.listCategory.remove(<the position of that detail>);
```

**declare your adapter also as instance variable of your activity class.**

**no need of your refreshDisplay method just use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in onActivityResult() method**

Comment: How can I get a reference to the adapter in *onActivityResult()* so I can use *adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()*?

Comment: see updated answer.actually when you set the adapter as instance variable of activity class you automatically get the reference of adapter as it is local of activity class

Comment: My adapter is inside refreshDisplay. Based on the category that is chosen from another list, the adapter lists different items. Now, if I want to use *adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()* inside *onActivityResult()* I need a reference to the **adapter**. How can I do that?

Comment: What is listCategory you use? is it the listView I used?

Comment: its your list which you are using for your listview

Comment: My code is quite large. I posted the relevant parts. The codes I posted above are all in the *MainActivity* (not nested)

Comment: You just delete that method and declare listview, adapter and your listCategory at class level.

Comment: Check my question again please. I have a drawer navigation that contains a list of categories. When I click on one of the categories, In my content fragment the **onCreateView** calls **refreshDisplay** ** and puts **context** & **View** arguments plus **category** & **i** which are the name and position of the category chosen. Now **refreshDisplay** takes those arguments and and creates the list of items of that category and shows it in the content Fragment. refreshDisplay has a list adapter and listener that when clicked opens *DetailActivity*.

Comment: What method do you mean I should delete? I think the adapter must initialized in the **refreshDisplay**. Would you please tell me how I can get a reference to it in **onActivityResult()**

Comment: I declared the adapter outside any method. I initialized it in refreshDisplay and I used it in onActiityResult with 'adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' But this did nothing and my list still won't update on return from DetailActivity.

Comment: tell me are you deleting the item of category in detail activity ? Be sure it is the same category which is used in mainactivity

Comment: Why did someone voted down this answer? Please explain!

Comment: i dont know why i m shocked

Comment: The problem still remains. I haven't been able to solve it. But thanks for your attention.